# Turn off notifications for Facebook group name changes

Tags: facebook-groups

I am wondering how I can stop getting notifications of name changes for groups that I am in. I have turned off notifications and even tried unfollowing groups to stop these name change notifications. I don't want to leave the groups I just want the notifications to stop.